# Why did ESV translate Ἄνδρες in Acts 27:10 as "Sirs" and in Acts 27:21 as "Men"?

Tags: acts

English Standard Version Acts 27:10

> saying, “**Sirs** [**Ἄνδρες**], I perceive that the voyage will be with **injury and much loss**, not only of the cargo and the ship, but also of our lives.”

Only 11 verses later, apparently addressing to the same group of people, we have:

English Standard Version Acts 27:21

> Since they had been without food for a long time, Paul stood up among them and said, “**Men** [**Ἄνδρες**], you should have listened to me and not have set sail from Crete and incurred this **injury and loss**.

Why did ESV translate Ἄνδρες as "Sirs" then later as "Men"?

Comment: Because *sir(e)* initially meant *male*, and *to sire* still means *to father*. It was so in the 1600s, when the KJV was first translated, and the ESV (indirectly) follows its usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek word ἀνήρ, ἀνδρός (aner, andros) always means "man".  However, when used as a form of address in the vocative plural, namely, ἄνδρες (andres), it might be equivalent to the English "gentlemen" as per BDAG.

The vocative plural occurs quite rarely in Acts 14:15, 19:25, 27:10, 21, 25.  Most versions translate these as "men" but some prefer "sirs"; but some like the ESV are just inconsistent.

Comment: There is no inconsistency of any kind; see my comment on the main post.